# Power BI Embedded Token Not allowing me to get report by id

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to use the Power BI API to load a Power BI Embedded report into my custom web app.

I login against AD

[image: Postman settings]

And then use that token to access the report list using

`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{{groupId}}/reports`

Then use the report ID selected to generate a token and then request the report by id for the embedded details.

Generate Token
`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{{groupId}}/reports/{{reportId}}/GenerateToken`

`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{{groupId}}/reports/{{reportId}}`

Calling the reports URL above gives me 403 Forbidden.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you share the response you're getting? especially response headers & body if there is any

Answer (score 1):

You can't get report id informations using the embed token , you should use the acces token for that.

Once you get the report embed url , use the embed token and the sdk client to integrate the report into your third party app.